# Json Path Read from a Kafka Message

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a kafka message like below, where im trying to read the data from the json path. However im having a challenge when reading some of the attributes from the json path. here is the sample message.

sample1:

```
{
  "header": {
    "bu": "google",
    "id": "12345",
    "bum": "google",
    "originTimestamp": "2021-10-09T15:17:09.842+00:00",
    "batchSize": "0",
    "jobType": "Batch"
  },
  "payload": {
    "derivationdetails": {
      "Id": "6783jhvvh897u31y283y",
      "itemid": "1234567",
      "batchid": 107,
      "attributes": {
        "itemid": "1234567",
        "lineNbr": "1498",
        "cat": "5929",
        "Id": "6783jhvvh897u31y283y",
        "indicator": "false",
        "subcat": "3514"
      },
      "Exception": {
        "values": [
          {
            "type": "PICK",
            "value": "blocked",
            "Reason": [
              "RULE"
            ],
            "rules": [
              "439"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rulesBagInfo": [
          {
            "Idtype": "XXXX",
            "uniqueid": "7889423rbhevfhjaufdyeuiryeukjbdafvjd",
            "rulesMatch": [
              "439"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sample 2: Same message but see the difference in "Payload"

```
{
  "header": {
    "bu": "google",
    "id": "12345",
    "bum": "google",
    "originTimestamp": "2021-10-09T15:17:09.842+00:00",
    "batchSize": "0",
    "jobType": "Batch"
  },
  "payload": {
      "Id": "6783jhvvh897u31y283y",
      "itemid": "1234567",
      "batchid": 107,
      "attributes": {
        "itemid": "1234567",
        "lineNbr": "1498",
        "cat": "5929",
        "Id": "6783jhvvh897u31y283y",
        "indicator": "false",
        "subcat": "3514"
      },
      "Exception": {
        "values": [
          {
            "type": "PICK",
            "value": "blocked",
            "Reason": [
              "RULE"
            ],
            "rules": [
              "439"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rulesBagInfo": [
          {
            "Idtype": "XXXX",
            "uniqueid": "7889423rbhevfhjaufdyeuiryeukjbdafvjd",
            "rulesMatch": [
              "439"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
  }
}
```

If you observe, sometimes the message has "derivationdetails", and sometimes it doesn't. But irrespective of its existence, i need to read the values of id,itemid and batchid. I tried using

```
$.payload[*].id
$.payload[*].itemid
$.payload[*].batchid
```

But i see that for batchid is returning null even though it has a value in the message, and the attributes under "attributes" return null if im using the above. For fields under "attributes" im using this(example):

```
$.payload.attributes.itemId
```

And, completely blank on how to read the below part.

```
"Exception": {
        "values": [
          {
            "type": "PICK",
            "value": "blocked",
            "Reason": [
              "RULE"
            ],
            "rules": [
              "439"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "rulesBagInfo": [
          {
            "Idtype": "XXXX",
            "uniqueid": "7889423rbhevfhjaufdyeuiryeukjbdafvjd",
            "rulesMatch": [
              "439"
            ]
```

Im new to this and need some suggestions on how to read the attributes properly. Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `..`(recursive descent, Deep scan. JSONPath borrows this syntax from E4X.) to get the values. But It will return a list if there are multiple entries with same key nested in deep.

Below `jsonpath` expressions will return a `list` with one item each for both sample1 and sample2

```
$.payload..attributes.Id
$.payload..attributes.itemid
$.payload..batchid
$.payload..Exception
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but payload..batchid returns a list, if there are multiple entries. How can we overcome this and return only either 1 value?

Comment: You need to give the sample where it has multiple entries so that I can help. Both sample in the post have only one batchid. It's similar to Id and itemid you need to either fetch from attributes or any other key that you have

Comment: got the issue, but one last question, what if i have an array of values inside  "rules": [
              "439","441","465"
            ], then how can i read this with all the values inside?

Comment: There is no difference if you have an array or single element inside rules the path should still be the same. `$.payload..Exception.values[*].rules[*]`